# FFT low-pass filter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, filtering, fft

Be warned, this is a newbie question.
I acquired some noisy data (a 1x200 pixel sclice from a grayscale image), for which I am trying to build a simple FFT low-pass filter. I do understand the general principle of the Fourier Transform, but I ran into trouble trying to implement it.
My script works well on example data, but behaves in a strange manner on my data.

I think I must be mixing dimensions at some point, but it's been quite a few long hours and I cannot find where! I suspect that, because the output (please see below) of `print(signal.shape)` is different between the example and real data. Furthermore, `scipy.fftpack.rfft(signal)` seems to do nothing to my signal instead of computing the function in the frequency domain, as it should.

## My script:

(will run out-of-the-box using example data, just by copy-pasting everything below `#example data`)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np    
from scipy.fftpack import rfft, irfft, fftfreq, fft, ifft
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#===========================================
#GETTING DATA AND SETTING CONSTANTS
#===========================================
REACH = 100
COURSE = 180
CENTER = (cx, cy)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
gray2 = gray.copy()

#drawing initial vector
cv2.line(gray, (cx, cy + REACH), (cx, cy - REACH), 0, 5)
cv2.circle(gray, (cx, cy + REACH), 10, 0, -1)
cv2.circle(gray, (cx, cy), REACH, 0, 5)

#flooding contour with white
cv2.drawContours(gray2, contours, index, 255, -1)

#real data
signal = gray2[(cy - REACH):(cy + REACH), (cx-0.5):(cx+0.5)]
time = np.linspace(0, 2*REACH, num=200)

#example data
time   = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) + np.cos(7*np.pi*time)

#=============================================
#THE FFT TRANSFORM & FILTERING
#=============================================
#signal filtering
f_signal = rfft(signal)
W = fftfreq(signal.size, d=time[1]-time[0])


cut_f_signal = f_signal.copy()
cut_f_signal[(W>5)] = 0

cut_signal = irfft(cut_f_signal)

#==================================
#FROM HERE ITS ONLY PLOTTING
#==================================

print(signal.shape)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

ax1 = plt.subplot(321)
ax1.plot(signal)
ax1.set_title("Original Signal", color='green', fontsize=16)

ax2 = plt.subplot(322)
ax2.plot(np.abs(f_signal))
plt.xlim(0,100)
ax2.set_title("FFT Signal", color='green', fontsize=16)

ax3 = plt.subplot(323)
ax3.plot(cut_f_signal)
plt.xlim(0,100)
ax3.set_title("Filtered FFT Signal", color='green', fontsize=16)

ax4 = plt.subplot(324)
ax4.plot(cut_signal)
ax4.set_title("Filtered Signal", color='green', fontsize=16)

for i in [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]:
    i.tick_params(labelsize=16, labelcolor='green')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

## The result on real data:

### parameters:

```
signal = gray2[(cy - REACH):(cy + REACH), (cx-0.5):(cx+0.5)]
time = np.linspace(0, 2*REACH, num=200)
```

#### filtering parameter:

```
cut_f_signal[(W<0.05)] = 0
```

### Output:

output of `signal.shape` is `(200L, 1L)`

[image: real data output]

## The result on example data:

### parameters:

```
signal = np.cos(5*np.pi*time) + np.cos(7*np.pi*time)
time   = np.linspace(0,10,2000)
```

#### filtering parameter:

```
cut_f_signal[(W>5)] = 0
```

### Output:

output of `signal.shape` is `(2000L,)`

[image: example data output]

Comment: For one `cut_f_signal[(W<0.05)] = 0` would act as a high-pass filter (with a very low cutoff so might not affect the signal as much as you'd think), not a low-pass (try cut_f_signal[(W>0.05)] = 0` for a low-pass with the same cut-off frequency).

Comment: To me it seams like you want to detect the existence of two frequencies in a noisy signal. This can be done much easier that with a Fourier transform. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/niccokunzmann/positioning_system/blob/master/signal_detection.ipynb But please answer the question: what do you want to achieve? What is the overall goal? I see this pattern often: you are not aware of a problematic assumption you make and ask at stackoverflow for help regarding an implementation detail. So, could you add more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I began to think about that, and after a time I realized the stupidity in my ways. My base data is an image, and I take a slice of it to generate the above signal.
So instead of trying to implement a less-than-satisfying home-brewed FFT filter to smoooth the signal, it is in fact much better and easier to smooth **the image** with one of the numerous battle-tested filters (gaussian, bilateral, etc.) available in equally numerous image libs (in my case, OpenCV)...

Thanks to the people that took the time to try and help!